# select box using ajax and CakePHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get data related to parent data from select options , and here's my add.ctp

```
 <select name="id" id="category">
                <option value="hide">-- اختر مجموعة الصنف --</option>
<?php foreach ($warehouseCategoriesItems as $warehouseCategoriesItem): ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $warehouseCategoriesItem; ?> "  ><?php echo $warehouseCategoriesItem; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
<select name="id" id="item">
   <option>-- اختر الصنف-- </option>
</select>
```

and here's the script for that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var types_list          =   $('#item');

$('#category').change(function(){
  carId = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '../warehouse-add-orders-items-form7/add/' + carId ,
     data: { 'carId': carId  },
      success: function( response ) {
        types_list.empty();
        types_list.append(
            $("<option></option>")
                 .text('-- إختر نوع  --')
                .val('')
        );

        $.each(response, function(id, name) {
            types_list.append(
                $("<option></option>")
                    .text(response[id].category_item_name)
                    .val(response[id].warehouse_categories_items_id)
            );
        });
        types_list.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }
    });
});
```

.There's relationship between the category parent and the child items , but i'm getting the child with null values each time and the parent back with it's value . 
can any one tell me the problem here ?

Comment: why name="id" in the select? TWICE

Comment: from the double table ?

Comment: The issue is here : $.each(response, function(id, name) {
                types_list.append(
                    $("<option></option>")
                        .text(response[id].warehouse_categories_items_id)
                        .val(response[id].warehouse_item_name)
                );
            });

Comment: please post an answer or update the question.